# Eclipse - Remote java debug not showing variable values

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging

I am remote debugging a java application in Eclipse. I start the remote application with following command;

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y,suspend=y -jar MyApp.jar
```

And manage to succesfully connect to it in Eclipse on the port 8001. I can debug it fine and my breakpoints will catch. But I can not inspect variable values in Eclipse while debugging, only method params are showing in the variables tab. When debugging local Java apps i can inspect all the variable values just fine, so I think my IDE setup is ruled out?

In my build.xml i have tried to enable debugging with

```
 <javac srcdir="@{srcdir}/java"
               includes="**"
               includeantruntime="false"
               encoding="utf-8"
               destdir="@{destdir}"
               source="1.6"
               target="1.6"
               debug="true"
               debuglevel="lines,vars,source">
            <classpath refid="@{classpathref}"/>
        </javac>
```

What am I missing here? Any pointers highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my (ant) build.xml was set up correctly. Simply needed a recompile of the project. The variables are showing in the variables tab now.

Answer (score 0):

Variables can be renamed in your .class file so you cannot inspect them by their name on .java.

You can use the Variables view (Window -> show view -> Variables (under Debug folder)) to inspect the value of all fields and local variables available to the current scope.